# Unable to add multiple objects to my state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component, which maps over an array and passes props down to a child component.

Within the child component (shared below), I give the user options to mark the Font awesome icons (which are checkboxes). Every time user checks a box, I make an object of their response and I'd like to add it to an array which I will then send to the backend.

But whenever the user clicks, the state array resets and adds the only the object that was just selected. Previous objects added are overridden.

```
this.state = {
      outputArray: [],
      outputObject: {}
    }
```

```
 render () {
   return (
     renderOptions (outerArray) {
       if (outerArray.length) {
         return (
           <div>
             {outerArray.map((outerElement, i) => {
               return outerElement.map(item => (
                 <div className="Box" key={i}>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheckCircle} 
                 className="checkIconStyling" onClick={() => this.collectUserFeedback(this.props.param, item.param1, item)} />
                <div>{outerElement.param3}</div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAngleDoubleRight} className="chevronIconStyling"  />
                <div>{item}</div>
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBug} className="bugIconStyling" />
              </div>
            ))
          })}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
 )
}
```

And this is the function that is called every time user presses an icon:

```
  collectUserFeedback (item1, item2, item3) {
    let result = {};
    result[item2] = item3;
    this.setState({
      outputObject: {
        'some_key': item1,
        'some_other_key': result
      }
    }, () => {
      this.setState({
        outputArray: [...this.state.outputArray, this.state.outputObject]
      }, () => {
        // should add multiple objects to this array:
        console.log(this.state.outputArray);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: why are you calling `setState` twice?

Comment: First to create the outer object and then to create an outer array. Just realized that it could probably be done in one.

Comment: Please provide full code of component with `collectUserFeedback`

Comment: Please, provide how `state` is  organized? It's not clear what `outputArray` is holding

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify the logic as follows:

```
collectUserFeedback(item1, item2, item3)  {
  this.setState (
    (state, props) => ({
      outputArray: [
        ...state.outputArray,
        {
          'some_key': item1,
          'some_other_key': {[item2] : item3},
        },
      ],
    }),
    () => {
      // should add multiple objects to this array:
      console.log (this.state.outerArray);
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. It's also adding the elements once. And resetting array when a different icon is clicked.

Comment: @monstermans You seem to be using 2 diff names for the state key, one place you use outputArray and other you use outerArray.

Comment: Yes thats a good catch. It should be outputArray. I applied your suggestion with outputArray and it didnt work :(

Comment: @monstermans It would be possible to help you further if you could share the currently running code via codepen or repl.